# Reading a text file into a two dimentional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, file-read

I have a text file that looks like the following.

```
5
2   7
3   4   2
```

Basically,
row 1 has 1 element,
row 2 has 2 elements,
row 3 has 3 elements,
...
up to n rows with n elements.

I need to read them, and put into a 2-d array in this fashion:

```
a[0][0] = 5
a[1][0] = 2
a[1][1] = 7
a[2][0] = 3
a[2][1] = 4
a[2][2] = 2
...
```

You get the drift.

However I know n (the number of rows) only at run time. How would I go about reading the file into a 2x2 array?

I know I can do the following if I know the number of elements in each line of text, and if that number is the same for each line.

```
fa = fopen("file.txt", "r");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fgets(str, 1000, fa);
    sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &a[i][0], &a[i][1], &a[i][2]);
}
fclose(fa);
```

But it wouldn't help me here as I have varying number of elements in each row.
How do I go about this?

Comment: You allocate a (two or one) dimensional array, probably using malloc & friends, step through the file line by line, and use a tokenizer (eg strtok) to step through the individual values in a line. That would be one way to do it.

Comment: Since you know how the number of values increases per line, you could just read each value at a time, with a single "%d". You just need to keep track of your i and j counters for the indices accuractly.

Comment: The best solution is to insert a line at the beginning of the file that has the value of `n`. That way, you know how big to make the array. Another easy approach is to read until the last line in the file, keeping track of the line count. The final line count will be `n`. Then `rewind` the file and read the values.

Comment: @Evert Tokenizers seem like a handy approach; thanks I'll see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate memory for the array like this:

```
int** array;

array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array)); /* Assuming `n` is the number of rows */
if(!array) /* If `malloc` failed */
{
    fputs(stderr, "Error allocating memory; Bailing out!");
    exit(-1);
}

int count = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(count * sizeof(**array));
    if(!array[i]) /* If `malloc` failed */
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) /* free previously allocated memory */
        {
            free(array[j]); 
        }
        free(array);

        fputs(stderr, "Error allocating memory; Bailing out!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Then, read data from the file into the array by using:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if(!fp)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* free previously allocated memory */
   {
      free(array[i]); 
   }
   free(array);

   fputs(stderr, "Error opening 'file.txt'; Bailing out!");
   exit(-1);
}

int max = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(count = 0; count < max; count++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i][count]);
    }
    max++;
}
```

Then print the results:

```
max = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(count = 0; count < max; count++)
    {
        printf("array[%d][%d] = %d", i, count, array[i][count]);
    }
    max++;
}
```

And finally, free the allocated memory:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   free(array[i]); 
}
free(array);
```